# Jquery UI Autocomplete List does not refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, websocket

So I am using jquery ui autocomplete where the list that is displayed is fetched via WebSockets. A call to fetch the list is made on every keystroke on the input field(.keyup()). Problem is that once I type in a character and a corresponding list is fetched and displayed, the next keystroke searches for the search parameter in the input field within the previous list instead of the new one that was fetched. To get the new options I need to press backspace. For example, if I enter "S" on the input, results corresponding to "S" will be fetched and displayed. If I further enter "h", making the search term "sh", then the list corresponding to "sh" is fetched, but the autocomplete searches for "sh" within the previous list. Simply put the list does not get refreshed immediately. How can I get the list to refresh immediately? Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:** So here's a bit of the code:
This is the part where the keystroke is detected and the search initiated

```
$('#pick_up_location').keyup(function(e) {
var param = $("#pick_up_location").val();                                  
var userType = "1";                                             
search(param, userType,"CBPickSearchAction", "", 0);
```

This is where the results received are displayed in autocomplete:

```
function onMessage(data) {
try
  {
    var obj =  $.parseJSON(data);
    $("#pick_up_location").autocomplete({
         source: obj,
             minLength: 0,
         delay: 0,
         autoFocus: true,
         search  : function() {
         },
            //open    : function(){$(this).removeClass('working'); $(".ui-autocomplete").width($(this).width());},
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
              },
              open    : function(event, ui){
                    $('#pick_up_location').autocomplete("widget").width(); 

             .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
              .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
              .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
              .appendTo( ul );
          };

          $("#pick_up_location").autocomplete('enable');
          $("#pick_up_location").keydown();
  } catch(err)
      {
        //console.log( err.message);
      }
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you included your code.

Comment: I updated my post with code

Comment: It's kind of hard to see any potential problems when the code is incomplete (there's a couple of missing braces and parentheses) and not correctly indented. Could you fix your code sample? Or perhaps create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The code was posted just to give an idea of how I'm implementing the autocomplete. Wasn't really aiming at it being syntatically correct when I copied and pasted it here. There's no possible way I can show it running in a jsfiddle. It's part of a much larger application that I'm working on. The autocomplete list is being fetched from a database at the backend.

Comment: I understand. Still, it makes it hard to spot any problems. My suggestions would be to try to simplify your code until it's it works (or start from a simple example) and then add one piece at a time. It might even give you a better understanding of how the component works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found a solution. The problem was that usually when retrieving a list for autocomplete from another domain, an ajax call is made to return results to the source. However, since my goal was to make this commercial application whilst substituting all ajax calls with the use of websockets, the autocomplete wasn't working as desired. Also, I had restricted myself to making all API calls with just a single websocket opened.

All I had to do was to make a new connection in javascript to the websocket in Java and use its onmessage function to receive the results and place them in the response of the autocomplete. Previously, the autocomplete's source was a var that contained the results when they had been returned. But this was not exactly working as desired because on every keystroke it just searched through the results already there. You would have to enter backspace for the list to refresh.

Here's the modified code snippet:

```
function locationSearch() {
     $("#pick_up_location").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            var action = "CBPickSearchAction";
            var userType = 1;
            var requestString = createRequestStringForLocationSearch(action, userType, request.term);
            webSocket_local.send(requestString);

            webSocket_local.onmessage = function(event) {
                data = event;
                data = formatLocationResponse(data, action);
            response($.parseJSON(data));
            };
        },
         minLength: 0,
         delay: 0,
         autoFocus: true,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
              },
              open    : function(event, ui){
                    $('#pick_up_location').autocomplete("widget").width(); 
            },
          .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
              .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
              .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
              .appendTo( ul );
          };
}



  $('#pick_up_location').keyup(function(e) {
       locationSearch();
}
```

Thus my goal to create an ajax-free web application was accomplished. :)

If anyone has an even better solution, I'd be interested in knowing.